# Android how to create an edittext that look like google login edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Is there any way to create a textfield in java that will look like one in the picture below?
[image: this is a sample of edittext i want create]

i want know if i can extends `EditText` and create my own using custom `EditText` like floating label EditText

i want make it bordered and the hint display inside the stroke like that shown in the image above.

thanks.

Comment: Hm, why not? Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: The problem is that i dont how to draw  a line on top, left, or bottom of my edittext in java using canvas when i create a custom Edittext.   which is simple in html.

Comment: Google 'TextInputLayout' and how to style it. Or visit [here](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/android#outlined-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

This is material `TextInputLayout` specifically, outlined Text input layout found [here](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/android#outlined-text-field) in more detail.